# Forced horizontal scroolbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an issue that I could not find a solution for .. 
On mobile devices a forced horizontal scroll shows up ..

http://andreibilecatestwebsites.comxa.com/Tentrom%20-%20homepage/index2.html This is the website im testing it on ..

After my tries to find a solution I noticed that : the problem disappears only if I erase all the HTML code starting from line 120 all the way till line 164 . This means the entire section .

I tried leaving the code there and erasing the  entire styling sheet related to that and the responsive style shit , but the problem persisted .

So im pretty sure I did something with the HTML code .
Thanks for the help

```
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="backgroundimage">
          <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">
      <a href="#contactform"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary buton center-block buttonform">CONTACTEAZA-NE </button></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-offset-8 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2 formular">
      <h3>CONTACTEAZA-NE</h3>
      <p>Lasa-ne mesajul tau pentru a fi contactat ulterior:</p>
                     <!-- TRATORIA FORM STARTS HERE -->
        <form class="form" id="contactform" action="contact.php" method="post">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="Prenumele tau:">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Nmele tau:">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Adresa ta de email:">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Numarul tau de telefon:">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Mesajul tau:"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary buton center-block">Trimite </button>
        </form>
        </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What mobile resolution are you seeing a horizontal scroll bar appear on? I tested your link on a variety of responsive tools and cannot see it.

Comment: yea it only shows on phones .. 
I tested in on 3 phones and its there .. its not showing up on any responsive tools either

Comment: You shouldn't have row as immediate child of row due to negative margins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missing `</div>` in the sharedcode, check it and update.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="backgroundimage">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">
                        <a href="#contactform"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary buton center-block buttonform">CONTACTEAZA-NE </button></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-offset-8 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2 formular">
                        <h3>CONTACTEAZA-NE</h3>
                        <p>Lasa-ne mesajul tau pentru a fi contactat ulterior:</p>
                        <!-- TRATORIA FORM STARTS HERE -->
                        <form class="form" id="contactform" action="contact.php" method="post">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="Prenumele tau:">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Nmele tau:">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Adresa ta de email:">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Numarul tau de telefon:">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Mesajul tau:"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary buton center-block">Trimite </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

and you have a BAD Nesting try This you can apply to one row nesting the background img, and nest into it all col you need:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row backgroundimage">
        <div class="col-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <a href="#contactform"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary buton center-block buttonform">CONTACTEAZA-NE </button></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-offset-8 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2 formular">
            <h3>CONTACTEAZA-NE</h3>
            <p>Lasa-ne mesajul tau pentru a fi contactat ulterior:</p>
            <!-- TRATORIA FORM STARTS HERE -->
            <form class="form" id="contactform" action="contact.php" method="post">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="Prenumele tau:">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Nmele tau:">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Adresa ta de email:">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Numarul tau de telefon:">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="3" placeholder="Mesajul tau:"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary buton center-block">Trimite </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is still there

Comment: send the CSSS you use to force the scroll

Comment: I do not understand why you want the horizontal bar simply is not horizontal content you need this displacement.

Comment: Checked the update the problem is gone ! thanks a bunch

Comment: ok, placed as it solved, it is good to leave documented for others. if it was my solution remember to mark an answer and solved.